# extjs 4.2.1 - center align text in label

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

I have a Ext.form.Label component in ExtJS.  In the label I have 2 lines of text.  How do I horizontally center both of these lines of text?  For example:

```
ABC
 B
```

I tried putting `span` tags around each line and styling them with `text-align:center` but both of the text are still left aligned.

EDIT:
added some code:

```
label.update('<span>ABC</span><br>'+
             '<span>B</span>');
```

Comment: using html instead of text in Ext.form.label

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for all the answer guys.  I figured it out:

```
label.setText('ABC<br/>B');
```

Then in your label config, you simply define the style property like this:

```
style: 'display:inline-block;text-align:center'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are exctly trying to do, do you have some code? To center things with spans, the spans must be the same width, so add this to your css code:

```
display:inline-block;
width:40px;
```

The `display:inline-block;` is because normal spans don't accept widths.

[See this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F2442/)

Comment: I tried these properties, but the text is still getting left aligned.  It might be an ExtJS specific thing

Comment: Nevermind I got your solution to work.  I just inlined the css in the HTML.  I had all the css stuff in another file before and it wasn't changing any of the selectors I specified. How can i get the spans to wrap around the length of the text instead of hardcoding a width?  I noticed that for a string that's separated by spaces, the words that don't fit on a single line wrap and appear on the next line.

Comment: That is hard to do, as the widths of both spans must be the same. Using `width:inherit;` on on the spans and a div around them width a set width (eg. in px, cm or %). See the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F2442/1/)

Answer (score 0):

adding the span to the `fieldLabel` config of the `textfield` works.

You will need to uses `display:inline-block` because ExtJs adds a ":" at the end of your label.

```
   {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'email',
        fieldLabel: '<span style="display:inline-block; text-align:center;">Really long top<br/>small</span>',
    }
```

working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/eLnu5/